# White bars on either react web app when viewing on landscaped mobile device

Tags: html, css, reactjs, vite

I built and deployed a react app with vite and when viewing on mobile screens that are turned landscape I get white bars on either side. I have seen some articles here and on the web to do various things with css and such to try to remove it, to no avail.

CSS I've tried so far:

```
@media (orientation: landscape) {
  html, body {
    width: 100%; 
    overflow-x: hidden; 
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0;
  }
}

html, body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

@media (orientation: landscape) {
  #app {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    height: 100vh; 
    overflow-x: hidden;
    margin: 0 auto;
  }
}

#app {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100vh; 
  overflow-x: hidden;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

I also tried to make the viewport-fit=cover adjustment to my html:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, viewport-fit=cover">
```

Nothing seems to be working for mobile views. Testing this with Chrome DevTools and turning the emulated device sideways doesn't seem to show this, but on my actual mobile device I see the white lines. Does anyone know what is causing this? I'm not sure if this is a react issue, a device issue, a  setting of some sort, maybe something vite does, or plain old css/html adjustments that need to be made. Picture below:

[image]